# How to display my python code in a table on Django webpage?

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-templates, django-views

I have written some code in Python that reads in two strings, removes the punctuation and then compares the words in them within a matrix table which it prints to the console.

How do I convert the code to be utilised within the Django framework. I want to display a similar matrix on the web. I've already imported it into views. Please may someone point me in the right direction? I've been using django project and lynda to learn as I go along,

Edit:

Merci for the help guys. Managed to get it to display on a webpage. But it is printing it all out as a single string. How do I style it a bit better?

[image: originalpythoncode]
[image: djangowebpage]

Comment: you should send your `out` as context variable to render your templare.

Comment: cheers finally got to that... now I'm trying to figure out how to get it to display correctly.

Comment: remove your answer, and create new quetion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send your data to your template you should add your variable to context at your views

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from polls.models import Poll

def detail(request, poll_id):
    ... // your logic
    out // your variable
    return render(request, 'yourhtml.html', {'out': out})
```

In html will be like that

```
{{ out }}

{% for o in out %}
    {{ o }}
{% endfor %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/views/

You can style your table with some CSS or using ny lib struct to handle tables

You can follow this guide

[display django-pandas dataframe in a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003732/display-django-pandas-dataframe-in-a-django-template)

Comment: thanks for the help... been trying to work my way through it, Tried following the 2nd link but kinda confusing as our code is quite different.

Comment: thank you... got there in the end. It displays the data like this:
Oh you can't kelp that said the Cat we're all mad deer \ Oh 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 you 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 can't 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 help 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 that 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 said 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 the 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 Cat 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 we're

Comment: You need to preper your variable to be used in template, in the last link i placed there is a example in how to handle data frames in html

Answer (score 2):

Think of passing your data to a "Django webpage" as just passing a dictionary of your values to a Django template from your Django view.

**What is a Django template?** 
A Django template is the 'T' in Django's 'MTV' design pattern. In the conventional MVC design pattern (Model-View-Controller), the View is where you display things. In Django, Templates are where you display things. Oddly enough, the 'View' in Django is actually the Controller. This took me a while to wrap my head around.

**Why do we use a dictionary-like context?**
By mapping keys to values we achieve super-fast [O(1)/constant] lookup in the Django templates.

With all of this in mind, I'd advocate using 'TemplateView' generic view, doing your work in a utils file, importing utils into views, and then passing your data to the template via the context dictionary. So it would look something like this:

### local_utils.py

```
import string
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

def generate_out_matrix():

    with open('./arrayattempts/samp.txt', 'r') as file1:
        sampInput=file1.read().replace('\n', '')
        #print(sampInput)

    with open('./arrayattempts/ref.txt', 'r') as file2:
        refInput=file2.read().replace('\n', '')
        #print(refInput)

    sampArray = [word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in sampInput.split()]
    refArray = [word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in refInput.split()]

    out=pd.DataFrame(index=refArray,columns=sampArray)

    for i in range(0, out.shape[0]):
        for word in sampArray:
            out.ix[i,str(word)] = out.index[i].count(str(word))

    return out.as_matrix()
```

### views.py

```
from appname.local_utils import generate_out_matrix
class Detail(TemplateView):      
    template_name = 'appname/yourhtml.html'

    # Will render on each call to URL for 'Detail'
    def get_context_data(self):
        out = generate_out_matrix()
        context['out'] = out
        return context
```

### appname/templates/yourhtml.html

```
{% if out %}
    {% for row in out_matrix %}
         {% for o in row %} 
              {{ o }}
         {% endfor %}
         <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

### urls.py

```
path('/your_path', views.Detail.as_view()),
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context

Comment: What I've done beforehand displays albeit without formatting... I'm currently trying your way and trying to refer to local_utils in view but it says unresolved reference. Thanks btw.

Comment: figured it out... had to do app.local_utils.py

Comment: Hey! Sorry, had to go to lunch. Did you get to it working? I was going to edit further but got pulled away. I agree w/ Diego that you need to prepare the data a bit more before passing to context. I'd recommend passing a list of lists then doing a double loop (with a line break)

Comment: @Brandon - I added the <br> and double loop example also

Comment: @Brandon - Can you let me know if the formatting works with returning '        return out.as_matrix()'?