# Rendering a pandas dataframe on-page in django

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have created a page with Django where you can upload an excel file and it will save into the /media folder. Once it's uploaded, there is a page that shows a table of the uploaded files. I have added a 'View' button, and the expected behavior would be to pd.read_excel, then do a df.to_html, and then render that html on the same page.

There have been several other questions regarding how to do this, but they don't seem to fit my specific use case.

Any help you can provide on making the function and rendering it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Did you try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003732/display-django-pandas-dataframe-in-a-django-template ?

Comment: It would be useful to see the code you've written, what that has rendered, and how you expect it to render.