# Displaying Panda Table from other python project in Django App

Tags: python, django, pandas

So I am looking to display a Pandas table on a Django website through a django app. I have found this thread: [display django-pandas dataframe in a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003732/display-django-pandas-dataframe-in-a-django-template). This explains how to use bootstrap and JS to create the table and display it in Django.

However where I am lost is how I import the panda table to the object in the django.

Basically, I have python project that creates pandas based on information queried data from elsewhere. Now I am trying to display those pandas on my web app.

So, where I am lost is how I can run that python code (from my python pandas project) to get most recent data in sync with running the website and thus assign the pandas to the product model object. Any information regarding this would be huge. Thanks in advance!

I am trying to use bootstrap-tables, because it is interactive and can create many different tables, but if someone has an easier less complicated idea please let me know.

EDIT: The comment I made: So I did figure out a way to execute it in manage.py. Right now I have code that generates the photos for my website and that works. And I am sure I can make it execute in views as well. My question is now, is how can I take this panda dataframe and turn it into a interative table on my website. I have seen bootstrap-tables and DataTables, but have yet to make them work yet. Does anyone have a good guide for these to use on django? Also, I want the dataframe to be updated everytime the site is refreshed does this happen when it is in manage.py or in view.py?

Comment: Can you put the code to fetch the dataframe in a view, and call it when the view is executed? Or, are you trying to cache the information in the database so you don't need to fetch it each time?

Comment: So I did figure out a way to execute it in manage.py. Right now I have code that generates the photos for my website and that works. And I am sure I can make it execute in views as well. My question is now, is how can I take this panda dataframe and turn it into a interative table on my website. I have seen bootstrap-tables and DataTables, but have yet to make them work yet. Does anyone have a good guide for these to use on django? Also, I want the dataframe to be updated everytime the site is refreshed does this happen when it is in manage.py or in view.py?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.